# Magento2 - How to install extension when it contain composer.json file

Tags: extensions, magento2.3.3

I have an extension It contain `composer.json` file. How should I install this extension. I am using `Magento2.3.3` and `Window 10 OS`. If there is any command to install. Please let me know.

Comment: Just install like other extension.